# undici node make api request with header for Authorization

Tags: node.js, api, request, undici

im trying to make a api request with undici

```
const apiRequest = await request("https://example.com")
const apiJson = await apiRequest.body.json()
const info = apiJson.data
```

which works so far...
but with another API that I want to use, verification is done via the header.

```
Authorization: xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
```

but I can't find in the docs exactly how it works with undici

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization header can be added to the request as follows:

```
const apiRequest = await request('https://example.com', {
  headers: { Authorization: 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx' },
});
const apiJson = await apiRequest.body.json();
const info = apiJson.data;
```